# Maven error "Archetype catalog is empty" while creating Maven project for WebDriver with TestNG

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, selenium

I couldn't able to add maven artifact "ru.stqa.selenium" in eclipse.
I downloaded the catalog file from : "https://github.com/barancev/webdriver-testng-archetype"
Steps I followed is Eclipse-> Window-> Preference -> Maven-> ArchTypes-> Add Local Catalog.
On Local Archtype catalog popup I have put 
Catalog file location: Address of pom file from local as "D:\Software\Selenium\webdriver-testng-archetype-master\src\main\resources\archetype-resources".
Description : Some name

Now I am getting this warning message " Archetype catalog is empty".

If I go with Add Remote catalog with remote location as "http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/archetype-catalog.xml" , it works fine.

Curious to know the reason for this strange behavior.

Comment: I'd guess you're behind a proxy. Try http://stackoverflow.com/q/7737710/290182

Answer (score 0):

Effective January 15, 2020, The Central Repository no longer supports insecure communication over plain HTTP and requires that all requests to the repository are encrypted over HTTPS.

If you're receiving this error, then you need to replace all URL references to Maven Central with their canonical HTTPS counterparts:

Replace http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/ with https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/

Replace http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/ with https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/

If for any reason your environment cannot support HTTPS, you have the option of using our dedicated insecure endpoint at http://insecure.repo1.maven.org/maven2/

For further context around the move to HTTPS, please see https://blog.sonatype.com/central-repository-moving-to-https.