# Problems using Maven and SSL behind proxy

Tags: java, maven, ssl, proxy

I just downloaded Maven and was trying to run the simple command found on the "Maven in Five Minutes" page (http://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/maven-in-five-minutes.html). This is the command:

```
mvn archetype:generate -DgroupId=com.mycompany.app -DartifactId=my-app -DarchetypeArtifactId=maven-archetype-quickstart -DinteractiveMode=false
```

When I run it I get an error with SSL certificate and cannot download from the central Maven repository at https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2. The error is "SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target".

I am sitting behind a corporate firewall and have correctly configured the proxy settings for both `http` and `https` access via the `settings.xml` file. I doubt that everyone who downloads Maven and runs it for the first time has to import the SSL certificate of the Maven repository, so the problem must be with the proxy. Does anyone have any experience with this?

Here's the stack trace in full debug mode (-X):

```
 mvn archetype:generate -DgroupId=com.mycompany.app -DartifactId=my-app -DarchetypeArtifactId=maven-archetype-quickstart -DinteractiveMode=false

Apache Maven 3.2.3 (33f8c3e1027c3ddde99d3cdebad2656a31e8fdf4; 2014-08-11T22:58:10+02:00)
    Maven home: C:\Projects\maven\bin\..
    Java version: 1.7.0_45, vendor: Oracle Corporation
    Java home: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_45\jre
    Default locale: it_IT, platform encoding: Cp1252
    OS name: "windows 7", version: "6.1", arch: "amd64", family: "windows"
    [DEBUG] Using connector WagonRepositoryConnector with priority 0.0 for https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 via *****:8080 with username=*****, password=***
    Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-clean-plugin/2.5/maven-clean-plugin-2.5.pom
    [WARNING] Failed to retrieve plugin descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:2.5: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:2.5 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:jar:2.5
    org.apache.maven.plugin.PluginResolutionException: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:2.5 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:jar:2.5
            at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultPluginDependenciesResolver.resolve(DefaultPluginDependenciesResolver.java:122)
            at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultMavenPluginManager.getPluginDescriptor(DefaultMavenPluginManager.java:148)
            at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.loadPlugin(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:81)
            at org.apache.maven.plugin.prefix.internal.DefaultPluginPrefixResolver.resolveFromProject(DefaultPluginPrefixResolver.java:138)
            at org.apache.maven.plugin.prefix.internal.DefaultPluginPrefixResolver.resolveFromProject(DefaultPluginPrefixResolver.java:121)
            at org.apache.maven.plugin.prefix.internal.DefaultPluginPrefixResolver.resolve(DefaultPluginPrefixResolver.java:85)
            at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoDescriptorCreator.findPluginForPrefix(MojoDescriptorCreator.java:260)
            at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoDescriptorCreator.getMojoDescriptor(MojoDescriptorCreator.java:220)
            at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.DefaultLifecycleTaskSegmentCalculator.calculateTaskSegments(DefaultLifecycleTaskSegmentCalculator.java:103)
            at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.DefaultLifecycleTaskSegmentCalculator.calculateTaskSegments(DefaultLifecycleTaskSegmentCalculator.java:83)
            at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:85)
            at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:347)
            at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:154)
            at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:582)
            at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:214)
            at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:158)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
            at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
            at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
            at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
            at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
            at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
    Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.resolution.ArtifactDescriptorException: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:jar:2.5
            at org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.loadPom(DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.java:349)
            at org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.readArtifactDescriptor(DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.java:231)
            at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultRepositorySystem.readArtifactDescriptor(DefaultRepositorySystem.java:288)
            at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultPluginDependenciesResolver.resolve(DefaultPluginDependenciesResolver.java:108)
            ... 23 more
    Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.resolution.ArtifactResolutionException: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:pom:2.5 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
            at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:459)
            at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifacts(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:262)
            at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifact(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:239)
            at org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.loadPom(DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.java:334)
            ... 26 more
    Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.transfer.ArtifactTransferException: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:pom:2.5 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
            at org.eclipse.aether.connector.wagon.WagonRepositoryConnector$6.wrap(WagonRepositoryConnector.java:1016)
            at org.eclipse.aether.connector.wagon.WagonRepositoryConnector$6.wrap(WagonRepositoryConnector.java:1004)
            at org.eclipse.aether.connector.wagon.WagonRepositoryConnector$GetTask.run(WagonRepositoryConnector.java:725)
            at org.eclipse.aether.util.concurrency.RunnableErrorForwarder$1.run(RunnableErrorForwarder.java:67)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
    Caused by: org.apache.maven.wagon.TransferFailedException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
            at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.AbstractHttpClientWagon.fillInputData(AbstractHttpClientWagon.java:935)
            at org.apache.maven.wagon.StreamWagon.getInputStream(StreamWagon.java:116)
            at org.apache.maven.wagon.StreamWagon.getIfNewer(StreamWagon.java:88)
            at org.apache.maven.wagon.StreamWagon.get(StreamWagon.java:61)
            at org.eclipse.aether.connector.wagon.WagonRepositoryConnector$GetTask.run(WagonRepositoryConnector.java:660)
            ... 4 more
    Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
            at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192)
            at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1884)
            at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:276)
            at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:270)
            at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1341)
            at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:153)
            at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:868)
            at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Handshaker.java:804)
            at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1016)
            at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1312)
            at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1339)
            at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1323)
            at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.createLayeredSocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:280)
            at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.conn.HttpClientConnectionOperator.upgrade(HttpClientConnectionOperator.java:167)
            at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.upgrade(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:329)
            at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.establishRoute(MainClientExec.java:392)
            at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:218)
            at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:194)
            at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:85)
            at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:108)
            at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:186)
            at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:82)
            at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.AbstractHttpClientWagon.execute(AbstractHttpClientWagon.java:756)
            at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.AbstractHttpClientWagon.fillInputData(AbstractHttpClientWagon.java:854)
            ... 8 more
    Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
            at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:385)
            at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(PKIXValidator.java:292)
            at sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Validator.java:260)
            at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:326)
            at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:231)
            at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:126)
            at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1323)
            ... 27 more
    Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
            at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(SunCertPathBuilder.java:196)
            at java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(CertPathBuilder.java:268)
            at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:380)
            ... 33 more
```

Comment: I solved it following [rec's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21266642/2503185) to ignore SSL certificate checking.

Answer (score 196, accepted):

The fact is that your maven plugin try to connect to an https remote repository
(e.g https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/)

This is a new SSL connectivity for Maven Central was made available in august, 2014 !

So please, can you verify that your settings.xml has the correct configuration.

```
    <settings>
      <activeProfiles>
        <!--make the profile active all the time -->
        <activeProfile>securecentral</activeProfile>
      </activeProfiles>
      <profiles>
        <profile>
          <id>securecentral</id>
          <!--Override the repository (and pluginRepository) "central" from the
             Maven Super POM -->
          <repositories>
            <repository>
              <id>central</id>
              <url>http://repo1.maven.org/maven2</url>
              <releases>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
              </releases>
            </repository>
          </repositories>
          <pluginRepositories>
            <pluginRepository>
              <id>central</id>
              <url>http://repo1.maven.org/maven2</url>
              <releases>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
              </releases>
            </pluginRepository>
          </pluginRepositories>
        </profile>
      </profiles>
    </settings>
```

You can alternatively use the simple http maven repository like this

```
 <pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
      <id>central</id>
      <name>Maven Plugin Repository</name>
      <url>http://repo1.maven.org/maven2</url>
      <layout>default</layout>
      <snapshots>
        <enabled>false</enabled>
      </snapshots>
      <releases>
        <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
      </releases>
    </pluginRepository>
  </pluginRepositories>
```

Please let me know if my solution works ;)

J.

Comment: Thanks for the quick and accurate response, it worked for me and will will probably help lots of people who start using maven after August 2014 :-) In the meantime I figured out how to make it work with SSL. I will post it as an answer below to help others out, but your answer will be the officially accepted one. Thanks

Comment: Thank you Andy ;) Both solutions work for you? or just the alternative ?

Comment: Yep, I tried it and it works. However, in the first code block I had to change both repository URLs from https to http, otherwise I got the same error message as before. Also, for anyone trying this, don't forget the <activeProfiles> tag.

Comment: Just tried with the second alternative simple soln, it worked for me... Thanks.

Comment: The first solution worked for me. But I also had to change from https to http like Andy advised. It may be better if you edit the answer. Great job guys, thanks

Comment: The 2nd solution worked. Old Java (6) and old Maven (3.2.5). And the employer's security is doing MITM.

Comment: How can I do the same with SBT?

Comment: Man absolutely you are perfect :) I found out nearly a week to solve it.Now works after changes...

Comment: Somehow I overlooked this answer and spent days trying to figure this out.  I still need my proxy specified in the settings.xml but this finally solved my issue

Comment: So you just changed https to http?

Comment: Hi @biology.info I am still facing some issues I tried to do both but got `could not calculate build plan: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-jar-plugin:2.4 or one of it's dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-jar-plugin:jar:2.4`. This error comes even If I connect my laptop to my home wifi and removing all the proxy settings also from settings.xml. Is it maybe because of firewall?

Comment: @biology.info My problem is coming while creating maven project either by skipping archetype or not.....but if I import other maven projects which precreated in another laptop then I can easily able to download dependencies no problem occurs

Comment: Effective January 15, 2020, The Central Repository no longer supports insecure communication over plain HTTP and requires that all requests to the repository are encrypted over HTTPS.

Comment: I love this solution more than the accepted one.

Answer (score 250):

The answer above is a good working solution, but here's how to do it if you want to use the SSL repo:

- Use a browser (I used IE) to go to https://repo.maven.apache.org/

  - Click on lock icon and choose "View Certificate"
  - Go to the "Details" tab and choose "Save to File"
  - Choose type "Base 64 X.509 (.CER)" and save it somewhere
- Now open a command prompt and type (use your own paths):

  `keytool -import -file C:\temp\mavenCert.cer -keystore C:\temp\mavenKeystore`
- Now you can run the command again with the parameter

  `-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=C:\temp\mavenKeystore`
- Under linux use absolute path

  `-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=/tmp/mavenKeystore`

  otherwise [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6784463/error-trustanchors-parameter-must-be-non-empty) will happen
- Like this:

  `mvn archetype:generate -DgroupId=com.mycompany.app -DartifactId=my-app -DarchetypeArtifactId=maven-archetype-quickstart -DinteractiveMode=false -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=C:\temp\mavenKeystore`

**Optional:**

You can use the `MAVEN_OPTS` environment variable so you don't have to worry about it again. See more info on the `MAVEN_OPTS` variable [here](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-repository-ssl.html):

Comment: This should be accepted as the correct answer. Your ISA proxy is inserting an intermediate certificate that is not trusted by the JDK.

Comment: I got maven working via command line. How do I get it working i eclipse?

Comment: Easy cut'n'paste for MAVEN_OPTS:  -Xmx512m -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=trust.jks -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword= -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore=/home/directory/mycertificate.p12 -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStoreType=pkcs12 -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=XXXXXX

Comment: This solved my problem. When it asks for the keystore password, the default is "changeit" if you haven't already changed it. :)

Comment: Also, on Ubuntu, you might run the command like `sudo keytool -import -file ./repo.maven.apache.org.crt -keystore /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/security/cacerts`

Comment: I used Chrome Version 54.0.2840.98 (64-bit) and I cannot export the Certificate

Comment: On Windows, I needed to combine this solution (I used Firefox to grab the certificate...lots of clicking around: More Information -> View certificate -> Details tab -> export)

... with [This stackoverflow solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11617210/how-to-properly-import-a-selfsigned-certificate-into-java-keystore-that-is-avail) to use Portecle to install it in the JRE on Windows

Comment: Not recommended as switching keystores will likely have undesirable side effects. Instead add the cert to existing keystore as described in Balaji's answer below.

Comment: Is a keyStore needed as well as a trustStore? Your answer implies not but the comment from Al Lelopath above and [these instructions](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-repository-ssl.html) imply it is. Not sure how to obtain a .p12 file though...

Answer (score 89):

You can use the `-Dmaven.wagon.http.ssl.insecure=true` option

Comment: Beautiful! Simplest and easiest for me.

Comment: simple and best answer

Answer (score 28):

## Update

I just stumbled on this bug report:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ca-certificates-java/+bug/1396760

It appears to be the cause of our problems here.  Something with ca-certificates-java encountering an error and not fully populating cacerts.  For me, this started happening after I upgraded to 15.10 and this bug probably occurred during that process.

The workaround is to execute the following command:

> sudo /var/lib/dpkg/info/ca-certificates-java.postinst configure

If you check the contents of the keystore (as in my original answer), you'll now see a whole bunch more, including the needed DigiCert Global Root CA.

If you went through the process in my original answer, you can clean up the key we added by running this command (assuming you did not specify a different alias):

> sudo keytool -delete -alias mykey -keystore /etc/ssl/certs/java/cacerts

Maven will now work fine.

---

## Original Answer

I'd just like to expand on Andy's answer about adding the certificate and specifying a keystore.  That got me started, and combined with information elsewhere I was able to understand the problem and find another (better?) solution.

Andy's answer specifies a new keystore with the Maven cert specifically.  Here, I'm going a bit more broad and adding the root certificate to the default java truststore.  This allows me to use mvn (and other java stuff) without specifying a keystore.

For reference my OS is Ubuntu 15.10 with Maven 3.3.3.

Basically, the default java truststore in this setup does not trust the root certificate of the Maven repo (DigiCert Global Root CA), so it needs to be added.

I found it here and downloaded:

https://www.digicert.com/digicert-root-certificates.htm

Then I found the default truststore location, which resides here:

> /etc/ssl/certs/java/cacerts

You can see what certs are currently in there by running this command:

> keytool -list -keystore /etc/ssl/certs/java/cacerts

When prompted, the default keystore password is "changeit" (but nobody ever does).

In my setup, the fingerprint of "DigiCert Global Root CA" did not exist (DigiCert calls it "thumbprint" in the link above).  So here's how to add it:

> sudo keytool -import -file DigiCertGlobalRootCA.crt -keystore
>   /etc/ssl/certs/java/cacerts

This should prompt if you trust the cert, say yes.

Use keytool -list again to verify that the key exists.  I didn't bother to specify an alias (-alias), so it ended up like this:

> mykey, Dec 2, 2015, trustedCertEntry, Certificate fingerprint (SHA1):
>   A8:98:5D:3A:65:E5:E5:C4:B2:D7:D6:6D:40:C6:DD:2F:B1:9C:54:36

Then I was able to run mvn commands as normal, no need to specify keystore.

Comment: Thanks to Andy. And to Leeland who reposted his blog.

http://nodsw.com/blog/leeland/2006/12/06-no-more-unable-find-valid-certification-path-requested-target

And to you too, @Luke.

Answer (score 13):

I actually had the same problem.

when I run

> mvn clean package

on my maven project, I get this certificate error by the maven tool.

I followed @Andy 's Answer till the point where I downloaded the **.cer** file

after that the rest of the answer didn't work for me but I did the following(I am running on Linux Debian machine)

first of all, run:

> keytool -list -keystore "Java path+"/jre/lib/security/cacerts""

for example in my case it is:

> keytool -list -keystore /usr/lib/jvm/jdk-8-oracle-arm32-vfp-hflt/jre/lib/security/cacerts

if it asks about the password, just hit enter.

this command is supposed to list all the ssl certificates accepted by the java.
when I ran this command, in my case I got 93 certificates for example.

Now add the downloaded file **.cer** to the **cacerts** file by running the following command:

> sudo keytool -importcert -file /home/hal/Public/certificate_file_downloaded.cer -keystore /usr/lib/jvm/jdk-8-oracle-arm32-vfp-hflt/jre/security/cacerts

write your sudo password then it will ask you about the **keystore password**

the default one is **changeit**

then say **y** that you trust this certificate.

if you run the command

> keytool -list -keystore /usr/lib/jvm/jdk-8-oracle-arm32-vfp-hflt/jre/lib/security/cacerts

once again, in my case, I got 94 contents of the **cacerts** file

it means, it was added successfully.

Comment: This is the most secure and transparent way to go if you trust the .cer file. Thanks for your contribution!

Comment: Any additional settings to configure after adding the certificate? The certificate is already added but I am still facing exactly the same issue.

Answer (score 13):

You can import the SSL cert manually and just add it to the keystore.

For linux users,

Syntax:

> keytool -trustcacerts -keystore /jre/lib/security/cacerts
>   -storepass changeit -importcert -alias nexus -file

Example :

> keytool -trustcacerts -keystore
>   /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_144.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/security/cacerts
>   -storepass changeit -importcert -alias nexus -file ~/Downloads/abc.com-ssl.crt

Comment: At first you still have to save the certificate as described in [Andy's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25912982/483113). So the extension would be ".cer".

Comment: Is it necessary to specify the certificate alias when running maven commands?

Answer (score 12):

If the situation is caused by a corporate firewall, and you are using Windows, your windows certificate store is likely configured to trust the firewall. You can tell Java to rely on the windows certificates by adding the option `-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStoreType=WINDOWS-ROOT` to the command line, or your MAVEN_OPTS.

Comment: additionally from maven 3.3.1 and ahead it can be added in your project dir as a config file.

${maven.projectBasedir}/.mvn/jvm.config

Answer (score 9):

This may not be the best solution. I changed my maven from 3.3.x to 3.2.x. And this issue gone.

Comment: I tried installing the certs for a couple hours with no luck, and this solution finally worked! The latest version of maven that I got to work was 3.2.2.

Comment: 3.3.3 and 3.2.5 didn't work for me, but 3.0.5 worked

Comment: I ended up here from a search engine, but am using Gradle instead of Maven. Updating my older version of Gradle also fixed these weird SSL issues for me.

Answer (score 8):

**Step 1:** GET the contents of the Certificate of the website( you want to have it imported as a trusted root)

```
$ keytool -printcert -rfc -sslserver maven.2xoffice.com*

-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIFNTCCBB2gAwIBAgIHJ73QrVnyJjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQsFADCBtDELMAkGA1UEBhMCVVMxEDAO
...
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIE3jCCA8agAwIBAgICAwEwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQEFBQAwYzELMAkGA1UEBhMCVVMxITAfBgNVBAoT
...
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIEADCCAuigAwIBAgIBADANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQUFADBjMQswCQYDVQQGEwJVUzEhMB8GA1UEChMY
...
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
The -rfc option outputs the certificate chain in PEM-encoded format for easy import back into a keystore.
```

**Step 2:** Save the whole thing (including the BEGIN CERTIFICATE and END CERTIFICATE lines, which are significant in this case) as godaddyg2.pem and imported it into my trust store via:

**Step 3:** Import the certificate in the keystore( java trusted key store)

```
$ keytool -importcert -file ./godaddyg2.pem -keystore $JRE_LIB/lib/security/cacerts
```

Answer (score 6):

It happens because your maven plugin try to connect to an **HTTPS** remote repository
(https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2) or (https://repo1.maven.apache.org).

Some time ago, you could to change these URL's to use HTTP instead use HTTPS, but since **January 15th 2020**, these URL's doesn't work any more, only the HTTPS URL's.

As an easy way to fix this problem, you can use the **insecure** Maven URL in the settings.xml file. So, you need to change ALL of yours references above mencioned to: http://insecure.repo1.maven.org/maven2/

TIP: Your JAVA_HOME variable always needs to point to your JDK path, not to your JRE path, for example: "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_80".

Answer (score 4):

What worked for me:

Configure `<proxy>` settings in `${MAVEN_HOME}/conf/settings.xml`:

(Note: For others, it worked when they configured `${user.home}/.m2/settings.xml`. If there is no settings.xml in user.home, just copy it from conf/ in the maven directory.)

```
  <!-- proxies
   | This is a list of proxies which can be used on this machine to connect to the network.
   | Unless otherwise specified (by system property or command-line switch), the first proxy
   | specification in this list marked as active will be used.
   |-->
  <proxies>
    <!-- proxy
     | Specification for one proxy, to be used in connecting to the network.
     |
    <proxy>
      <id>optional</id>
      <active>true</active>
      <protocol>http</protocol>
      <username>proxyuser</username>
      <password>proxypass</password>
      <host>proxy.host.net</host>
      <port>80</port>
      <nonProxyHosts>local.net|some.host.com</nonProxyHosts>
    </proxy>
    -->

    <proxy>
      <id>my-proxy</id>
      <active>true</active>
      <protocol>http</protocol>
      <username></username>
      <password></password>
      <host>my.proxy.host.com</host>
      <port>8080</port>
      <nonProxyHosts></nonProxyHosts>
    </proxy>

  </proxies>
```

Then point `pom.xml` to download from http maven central repo:

```
<project>
...
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>central</id>
            <name>Maven Plugin Repository</name>
            <url>http://repo1.maven.org/maven2</url>
            <layout>default</layout>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
            <releases>
                <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
            </releases>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
...
</project>
```

You may also need to configure http proxy in your IDE. For VSCode in `settings.json`:

```
{
    ...
    "http.proxy": "http://my/proxy/script/address/my-proxy.pac",
    ...
}
```

For Win10: Start/Search > Network proxy settings > Script address
[image]

Sources:

- [Maven proxy settings not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10033286/maven-proxy-settings-not-working)
- https://www.mkyong.com/maven/how-to-enable-proxy-setting-in-maven/
- https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-proxies.html
- https://maven.apache.org/settings.html#Proxies
- https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-repositories.html

Answer (score 4):

ymptom: After configuring Nexus to serve SSL maven builds fail with `peer not authenticated` or `PKIX path building failed`.

This is usually caused by using a self signed SSL certificate on Nexus. Java does not consider these to be a valid certificates, and will not allow connecting to server's running them by default.

You have a few choices here to fix this:

1. Add the public certificate of the Nexus server to the trust store of the Java running Maven
2. Get the certificate on Nexus signed by a root certificate authority such as Verisign
3. Tell Maven to accept the certificate even though it isn't signed

For option 1 you can use the `keytool` command and follow the steps in the below article.

Explicitly Trusting a Self-Signed or Private Certificate in a Java Based Client

For option 3, invoke Maven with `-Dmaven.wagon.http.ssl.insecure=true`. If the host name configured in the certificate doesn't match the host name Nexus is running on you may also need to add `-Dmaven.wagon.http.ssl.allowall=true`

> **Note**: These additional parameters are initialized in static
> initializers, so they have to be passed in via the `MAVEN_OPTS`
> environment variable.  Passing them on the command line to Maven will
> not work.

See [here](http://maven.apache.org/wagon/wagon-providers/wagon-http/) for more information:

Comment: This was the only thing that helped: `-Dmaven.wagon.http.ssl.insecure=true` from the command line

Answer (score 2):

A quick solution is add this code in your pom.xml:

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>central</id>
        <name>Maven Plugin Repository</name>
        <url>http://repo1.maven.org/maven2</url>
        <layout>default</layout>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </snapshots>
        <releases>
            <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
        </releases>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

Where never is for avoid the search a certified.

Comment: It is worth to scroll down in the answers thread. This worked simply!

Answer (score 2):

If you don't have the *.crt file and have access to maven web app (nexus etc),
The solution is (For firefox browser) :

1. Go to browser and access to themavenrepo.com
2. Click the lock icon in the top bar
3. Click 'Connection Secure' and then click 'More Information'
4. Click to 'Security' tab and click 'View Certificate'
5. in 'Miscellaneous' part, click the 'pem(cert)' to download
6. Go to terminal and run : openssl x509 -outform der -in downloaded.pem -out whatevernameyouwant.crt
7. sudo keytool -importcert -file whatevernameyouwant.crt -alias randomaliasname -keystore {your_java_installation_dir}/jre/lib/security/cacerts -storepass changeit

Answer (score 2):

I think best solution is to trust the root ca issued by your org (usually a self signed certificate, generated on the fly with your proxy tool) into system keystore.

1. Use the method given by @Andy in accepted answer to export the cert. (Make sure you select the `Base-64 encoded ASCII, certificate chain` option while saving it as .crt.
2. import and trust the root ca using below command
   `keytool -import -trustcacerts -cacerts -storepass changeit -noprompt -alias maven.pem -file <your .crt`
3. This imports into keystore used by JRE, you don't have to mess around with MAVEN_OPTS at all.

Answer (score 1):

I was getting the same error about the SSL certificate when Maven tried to download the necessary modules automatically. 
As a remedy, I was attempting to implement Luke's answer above, but found that the DigiCert Global Root CA certificate is already in Java's trusted keystore.
What helped me was adding `%JAVA_HOME%\bin` to the Path variable (I am running Windows). And `%JAVA_HOME%` is a JDK location, not just a JRE location, since Maven needs a JDK.
I am not certain why it helped, but it did. I am absolutely sure that this was the only thing I changed.

Answer (score 1):

If this issue happens for the **HTTPS** repository, f.e. https://repo.spring.io/milestone you can just try to replace with non secured: http://repo.spring.io/milestone. 
And that's it

Comment: each https repo does not have an http url

Answer (score 1):

After creating the keystore mentioned by @Andy.
In Eclipse, i added the jvm args and it worked.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Just a little beyond what Andy has put out.

You need to take the top most (root) certificate in case you happen to find a chain.

Took me one day to figure out.

Answer (score 1):

The maven.config file under .mvn diretory with the settings as given in MAVEN_OPTS to ignore SSL worked for me

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem in the same situation, and I wrote up a [detailed answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53514066/5711881) to a related question on stack overflow explaining how to more easily modify the system's cacerts using a GUI tool.  I think it's a little bit better than using a one-off keystore for a specific project or modifying the settings for maven (which may cause trouble down the road).

Answer (score 0):

Even though I was putting the certificates in cacerts, I was still getting the error.
Turns our I was putting them in jre, not in jdk/jre.

There are two keystores, keep that in mind!!!

Answer (score 0):

The issue, I got is
Earlier, I was using jdk 1.8.0_31 with certificate installed.
I switched to jdk 1.8.0_191 but did not install certificate.

But, my projects were working fine, I realized that their dependencies were downloaded already. So, they would only compile and package those projects.
But, this did not work for new maven projects as their dependencies were not downloaded earlier.

Solution::

1. Switch to earlier jdk version(which had certificate already installed) for your new project and do clean install
2. Download certificate again for the new jdk version that you have recently switched to and then do clean install

Answer (score 0):

Just another cause:
If you open Charles, you could also met this problem, in this case just quit Charles.

Comment: This answer is right. when I open Charles and use maven I got this exception. When I uncheck `macOS proxy` this exception disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with SSL and maven. My companies IT policy restricts me to make any changes to the computers configuration, so I copied the entire .m2 from my other computer and pasted it .m2 folder and it worked.

.m2 folder is usually found under c\user\admin

Answer (score 0):

For me the issue was that I had a preconfigured environment variable `JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS= -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore="company_truststore_path"`, but when using https://repo.maven.apache.org/ my truststore doesn't find maven's certificate on the specified truststore.

So, I have overridden this environment variable temporarily on the windows command line by setting it to empty string, here is the command  `set JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS=`, then, the build passed correctly.

Answer (score -2):

I simply used new java version and it worked for me.