# Can't build maven project

Tags: java, maven, spring-mvc, ssl

Trying to build project but always get error:

```
Failure to transfer org.apache.maven:maven-archiver:pom:2.6 from 
 https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the 
 local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update 
 interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced.
 Original error: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven:maven-archiver:pom:2.6 from/to 
 central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: No trusted certificate found
```

My pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
                    http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.some</groupId>
    <artifactId>someproj</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <name>someproj</name>


<build>
        <finalName>someproj</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${java.version}</source>
                    <target>${java.version}</target>
                </configuration>
                <version>3.1</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <java.version>1.7</java.version>
        <guava.version>17.0</guava.version>
        <spring.version>4.2.0.RELEASE</spring.version>
        <jackson.version>2.6.1</jackson.version>
    </properties>

</project>
```

I tryied to remove all .lastUpdated files from local repository, also change setting.xml like this [Problems using Maven and SSL behind proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25911623/problems-using-maven-and-ssl-behind-proxy)

Comment: try to build by using **clean -X install** command, so that you will get to know exact cause

Comment: Either import the certificate to your keystore or disable ssl checking for Maven.