# maven build failed on my jenkins, can any one help me to resolve

Tags: jenkins, maven-3

```
[ERROR] Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.5 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:jar:3.5: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:pom:3.5 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginResolutionException
[JENKINS] Archiving D:\maven\ISOListeners\TemenosBanking\pom.xml to COM.TEMENOS.BANK/ISOListeners/1.0-SNAPSHOT/ISOListeners-1.0-SNAPSHOT.pom
channel stopped
Finished: FAILURE
```

Comment: Check this look like same issue:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25911623/problems-using-maven-and-ssl-behind-proxy

Answer (score 0):

**Solution to your question**

1. You are trying to install certificate for accessing **http(s)** secured protocol to your local repository like Nexus/Archiva 
   **[Steps to create SSL certificates to your Java keystore](https://www.sslshopper.com/article-how-to-create-a-self-signed-certificate-using-java-keytool.html)**
2. You need administrator access to modify the JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/security/cacerts file.
3. Your keystore location will be in JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/security/cacerts
4. Ensure you have ***admin rights*** to perform this operation, You should definitely ***have admin rights to perform*** this operation