# Error while creating maven project

Tags: java

I have installed maven 3.3.9. Setup everything in eclipse. But still when creating maven project it is giving the following error. Can anyone please help me.

```
org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-quickstart:1.1 from any of the   configured repositories.
Could not resolve artifact org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-quickstart:pom:1.1
Failure to transfer org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-quickstart:pom:1.1 from https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-quickstart:pom:1.1 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderExcepti
```

Comment: Which command do you launch ?

Comment: I am very new to maven. I am trying to create the maven project in eclipse. I ran mvn -v to see the maven version. Other than that I didn't run any commands.

Comment: Here is my maven version                                                                                             Apache Maven 3.3.9 (bb52d8502b132ec0a5a3f4c09453c07478323dc5; 2015-11-10T
7+00:00)
Maven home: C:\Program Files (x86)\apache-maven-3.3.9\bin\..
Java version: 1.7.0_40, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_40\jre
Default locale: en_GB, platform encoding: Cp1252
OS name: "windows 7", version: "6.1", arch: "amd64", family: "windows"

Comment: you can launch mvn eclise:eclipse to create your project with maven then mvn build install to build it

Comment: I tried it but the build is failing

Comment: with the error that you have above or something else?

Comment: [ERROR] No plugin found for prefix 'eclipse' in the current project and in the plugin groups [org.apache.maven.plugins, org.codehaus.mojo] available from the repositories [local (C:\Users\sbattula\.m2\repository), central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2)]

Comment: oops my bad, it is mvn eclipse:eclipse

Comment: No good. [ERROR] No plugin found for prefix 'eclipse' in the current project and in the p
lugin groups [org.apache.maven.plugins, org.codehaus.mojo] available from the re
positories [local (C:\Users\sbattula\.m2\repository), central (https://repo.mave
n.apache.org/maven2)]

Comment: that's weird, try to drop your local repository which is here C:\Users\sbattula\.m2\repository and try again

Comment: It looks like an SSL error while connection to *https*://repo.maven.apache.org. Do you have corporate firewall that mangles all your Internet connections?

Comment: I removed the local repository and tried to create the maven project but still getting the same error. I have no idea where I am missing. We don't use any proxies.

Comment: PKIX error message definitely related to SSL (it's strange to get it without proxy). Check this question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25911623/problems-using-maven-and-ssl-behind-proxy

SHA1 of repo.maven.apache.org is `89 E2 9F 36 3F 10 86 BB B5 4F F0 02 16 AC E7 23 DC FD DB 3F`

Comment: I have imported the certificate. Stored in keystore. But still getting the error while creating the maven project. Please provide me more details.

Comment: I was able to run through command line but in eclipse I am still getting the same error

Comment: What is the code all about.' SHA1 of repo.maven.apache.org is 89 E2 9F 36 3F 10 86 BB B5 4F F0 02 16 AC E7 23 DC FD DB 3F'