# Maven SSL repo error with self signed cert and NTLM proxy

Tags: java, maven, ssl, proxy, ntlm

I am using Maven behind a corporate NTLM proxy.  I'm trying to build the Storm Starter project

https://github.com/apache/storm/tree/master/examples/storm-starter

but I get this exception

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 10.149 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2016-07-14T10:36:01-04:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 16M/280M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project storm-starter: Could not resolve dependencies for project org.apache.storm:storm-starter:jar:2.0.0-SNAPSHOT: Failed to collect dependencies at org.apache.storm:storm-clojure:jar:2.0.0-SNAPSHOT: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.storm:storm-clojure:jar:2.0.0-SNAPSHOT: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.storm:storm-clojure:pom:2.0.0-SNAPSHOT from/to clojars (https://clojars.org/repo/): sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal on project storm-starter: Could not resolve dependencies for project org.apache.storm:storm-starter:jar:2.0.0-SNAPSHOT: Failed to collect dependencies at org.apache.storm:storm-clojure:jar:2.0.0-SNAPSHOT
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleDependencyResolver.getDependencies(LifecycleDependencyResolver.java:221)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleDependencyResolver.resolveProjectDependencies(LifecycleDependencyResolver.java:127)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.ensureDependenciesAreResolved(MojoExecutor.java:245)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:199)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:307)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:193)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:106)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:863)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:288)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:199)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.project.DependencyResolutionException: Could not resolve dependencies for project org.apache.storm:storm-starter:jar:2.0.0-SNAPSHOT: Failed to collect dependencies at org.apache.storm:storm-clojure:jar:2.0.0-SNAPSHOT
        at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectDependenciesResolver.resolve(DefaultProjectDependenciesResolver.java:180)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleDependencyResolver.getDependencies(LifecycleDependencyResolver.java:195)
        ... 23 more
Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.collection.DependencyCollectionException: Failed to collect dependencies at org.apache.storm:storm-clojure:jar:2.0.0-SNAPSHOT
        at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.collectDependencies(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:291)
        at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultRepositorySystem.collectDependencies(DefaultRepositorySystem.java:316)
        at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectDependenciesResolver.resolve(DefaultProjectDependenciesResolver.java:172)
        ... 24 more
Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.resolution.ArtifactDescriptorException: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.storm:storm-clojure:jar:2.0.0-SNAPSHOT
        at org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.loadPom(DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.java:282)
        at org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.readArtifactDescriptor(DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.java:198)
        at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.resolveCachedArtifactDescriptor(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:535)
        at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.getArtifactDescriptorResult(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:519)
        at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.processDependency(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:409)
        at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.processDependency(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:363)
        at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.process(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:351)
        at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.collectDependencies(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:254)
        ... 26 more
Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.resolution.ArtifactResolutionException: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.storm:storm-clojure:pom:2.0.0-SNAPSHOT from/to clojars (https://clojars.org/repo/): sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
        at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:444)
        at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifacts(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:246)
        at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifact(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:223)
        at org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.loadPom(DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.java:267)
        ... 33 more
Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.transfer.ArtifactTransferException: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.storm:storm-clojure:pom:2.0.0-SNAPSHOT from/to clojars (https://clojars.org/repo/): sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
        at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.ArtifactTransportListener.transferFailed(ArtifactTransportListener.java:43)
        at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector$TaskRunner.run(BasicRepositoryConnector.java:355)
        at org.eclipse.aether.util.concurrency.RunnableErrorForwarder$1.run(RunnableErrorForwarder.java:67)
        at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector$DirectExecutor.execute(BasicRepositoryConnector.java:581)
        at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector.get(BasicRepositoryConnector.java:249)
        at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.performDownloads(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:520)
        at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:421)
        ... 36 more
Caused by: org.apache.maven.wagon.TransferFailedException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
        at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.AbstractHttpClientWagon.fillInputData(AbstractHttpClientWagon.java:1066)
        at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.AbstractHttpClientWagon.fillInputData(AbstractHttpClientWagon.java:960)
        at org.apache.maven.wagon.StreamWagon.getInputStream(StreamWagon.java:116)
        at org.apache.maven.wagon.StreamWagon.getIfNewer(StreamWagon.java:88)
        at org.apache.maven.wagon.StreamWagon.get(StreamWagon.java:61)
        at org.eclipse.aether.transport.wagon.WagonTransporter$GetTaskRunner.run(WagonTransporter.java:560)
        at org.eclipse.aether.transport.wagon.WagonTransporter.execute(WagonTransporter.java:427)
        at org.eclipse.aether.transport.wagon.WagonTransporter.get(WagonTransporter.java:404)
        at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector$GetTaskRunner.runTask(BasicRepositoryConnector.java:447)
        at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector$TaskRunner.run(BasicRepositoryConnector.java:350)
        ... 41 more
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
        at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1949)
        at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:302)
        at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:296)
        at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1509)
        at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:216)
        at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:979)
        at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Handshaker.java:914)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1062)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1375)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1403)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1387)
        at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.createLayeredSocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:275)
        at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.conn.HttpClientConnectionOperator.upgrade(HttpClientConnectionOperator.java:169)
        at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.upgrade(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:333)
        at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.establishRoute(MainClientExec.java:398)
        at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:219)
        at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:195)
        at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:86)
        at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:108)
        at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:184)
        at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:82)
        at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.AbstractHttpClientWagon.execute(AbstractHttpClientWagon.java:832)
        at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.AbstractHttpClientWagon.fillInputData(AbstractHttpClientWagon.java:983)
        ... 50 more
Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
        at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:387)
        at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(PKIXValidator.java:292)
        at sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Validator.java:260)
        at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:324)
        at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:229)
        at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:124)
        at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1491)
        ... 69 more
Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
        at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.build(SunCertPathBuilder.java:141)
        at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(SunCertPathBuilder.java:126)
        at java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(CertPathBuilder.java:280)
        at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:382)
        ... 75 more
[ERROR]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/DependencyResolutionException
```

I'm already using CNTLM and that has worked well in most instances.  I can browse to https://clojars.org/repo/.  When I look at the certificate in the browser I notice something interesting.  The certificate chain has my company's ROOT CA and the company proxy URL in the chain for the clojars.org cert.

I already have a section in my settings.xml to use http for maven central as this post mentions:
[Problems using Maven and SSL behind proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25911623/problems-using-maven-and-ssl-behind-proxy)

I tried something similar with my settings.xml for the clojars.org/repo but I still get this same error

```
<profile>
  <id>securecentral</id>
  <!--Override the repository (and pluginRepository) "central" from the
     Maven Super POM -->
  <repositories>
    <repository>
      <id>central</id>
      <url>http://repo1.maven.org/maven2</url>
      <releases>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
      </releases>
    </repository>
  </repositories>
  <pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
      <id>central</id>
      <url>http://repo1.maven.org/maven2</url>
      <releases>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
      </releases>
    </pluginRepository>
  </pluginRepositories>
</profile>
<profile>
  <id>secureclojars</id>
  <!--Override the repository (and pluginRepository) "central" from the
     Maven Super POM -->
  <repositories>
    <repository>
      <id>clojars</id>
      <url>http://clojars.org/repo/</url>
      <releases>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
      </releases>
    </repository>
  </repositories>
  <pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
      <id>clojars</id>
      <url>http://clojars.org/repo/</url>
      <releases>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
      </releases>
    </pluginRepository>
  </pluginRepositories>
</profile>
```

I also tried the other answer on the aforementioned post where I import the self signed cert into a keystore and reference its keystore as a JVM arg to the maven command.  This did not work either.  CORRECTION - I didn't get the same error the error I got was

```
[ERROR] Plugin org.apache.storm:storm-maven-plugins:2.0.0-SNAPSHOT or one of     its dependencies could not be resolved: Could not find artifact
 org.apache.storm:storm-maven-plugins:jar:2.0.0-SNAPSHOT in central     (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2) -> [Help 1]
```

I am suspicious of the cert chain having the proxy info in it, but I don't know what to make of that.

Comment: I found my mistakes: 1) read the readme: -> I need to build at the top level of the directory 2) import the MyCompany CA into a keystore  and not the self signed one because of the corporate proxy 3) once you have that CA then follow this step to build with maven at the root of the storm project: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25912982

Comment: although I consistently get this error: [ERROR] Plugin org.codehaus.mojo:appassembler-maven-plugin:1.9 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Could not transfer artifact
 org.codehaus.mojo:appassembler-maven-plugin:jar:1.9 from/to central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2): GET request of: org/codehaus/mojo/appa
ssembler-maven-plugin/1.9/appassembler-maven-plugin-1.9.jar from central failed: Premature end of Content-Length delimited message body (exp
ected: 1345749; received: 856717 -> [Help 1]