# MVN project is not being created

Tags: java, maven, netbeans, windows-7-x64

I am trying to create a web service using Maven using Netbeans 8.2 however, Nothing is created and am getting the following output.

```
cd D:\Applications\mavenproject1; "JAVA_HOME=C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk1.8.0_121\\jre" "M2_HOME=C:\\Program Files (x86)\\apache-maven-3.3.9" cmd /c "\"\"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\apache-maven-3.3.9\\bin\\mvn.cmd\" -DarchetypeGroupId=org.codehaus.mojo.archetypes -DarchetypeArtifactId=ejb-javaee7 -DarchetypeVersion=1.1 -DarchetypeRepository=http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 -DgroupId=com.iirosa -DartifactId=mavenproject1-ejb -Dversion=1.0-SNAPSHOT -Dbasedir=D:\\Applications\\mavenproject1 -Darchetype.interactive=false -Dmaven.ext.class.path=\"C:\\Program Files\\NetBeans 8.2\\java\\maven-nblib\\netbeans-eventspy.jar\" --batch-mode archetype:generate\""
Scanning for projects...
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-clean-plugin/2.5/maven-clean-plugin-2.5.pom
Failed to retrieve plugin descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:2.5: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:2.5 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:jar:2.5
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-install-plugin/2.4/maven-install-plugin-2.4.pom
Failed to retrieve plugin descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-install-plugin:2.4: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-install-plugin:2.4 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-install-plugin:jar:2.4
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-deploy-plugin/2.7/maven-deploy-plugin-2.7.pom
Failed to retrieve plugin descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.7: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.7 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:jar:2.7
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-site-plugin/3.3/maven-site-plugin-3.3.pom
Failed to retrieve plugin descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-site-plugin:3.3: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-site-plugin:3.3 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-site-plugin:jar:3.3
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-antrun-plugin/1.3/maven-antrun-plugin-1.3.pom
Failed to retrieve plugin descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-antrun-plugin:1.3: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-antrun-plugin:1.3 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-antrun-plugin:jar:1.3
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/2.2-beta-5/maven-assembly-plugin-2.2-beta-5.pom
Failed to retrieve plugin descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-assembly-plugin:2.2-beta-5: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-assembly-plugin:2.2-beta-5 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-assembly-plugin:jar:2.2-beta-5
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/2.8/maven-dependency-plugin-2.8.pom
Failed to retrieve plugin descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:2.8: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:2.8 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:jar:2.8
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-release-plugin/2.3.2/maven-release-plugin-2.3.2.pom
Failed to retrieve plugin descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-release-plugin:2.3.2: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-release-plugin:2.3.2 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-release-plugin:jar:2.3.2
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-metadata.xml
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/mojo/maven-metadata.xml
Could not transfer metadata org.apache.maven.plugins/maven-metadata.xml from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
Could not transfer metadata org.codehaus.mojo/maven-metadata.xml from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
Failure to transfer org.apache.maven.plugins/maven-metadata.xml from https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer metadata org.apache.maven.plugins/maven-metadata.xml from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
Failure to transfer org.codehaus.mojo/maven-metadata.xml from https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer metadata org.codehaus.mojo/maven-metadata.xml from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
------------------------------------------------------------------------
BUILD FAILURE
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Total time: 2.418 s
Finished at: 2017-01-31T14:58:29+03:00
Final Memory: 12M/309M
------------------------------------------------------------------------
No plugin found for prefix 'archetype' in the current project and in the plugin groups [org.apache.maven.plugins, org.codehaus.mojo] available from the repositories [local (C:\Users\Feras.Felimban\.m2\repository), central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2)] -> [Help 1]

To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.

For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/NoPluginFoundForPrefixException
```

Windows7 64 bit -- Netbeans 8.2 -- JDK8 update 121 -- apache-maven-3.3.9 -- glassfish 4.1.1

I have looked on the previous questions related to mine and have tried all suggested solutions but nothing worked. Environment Var are all set:

```
JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121
M2_HOME=C:\Program Files (x86)\apache-maven-3.3.9
MAVEN_HOME=C:\Program Files (x86)\apache-maven-3.3.9
MAVEN_OPTS=-Xms256m -Xmx512m
PATH=....;%M2_HOME%\bin;%M2%
```

[image]

Please note that the project is not being created at all, so its NOT the case that i am not being able to open a project.

I have visited the site that the output is showing but I had no luck (:

Your help is appreciated.

Comment: Looks like you are missing plugins.  The messages are clear.  You can get more info by rerunning with the -X and -e flags set.

Comment: @duffymo yup i know, i installed all related maven plugins from the IDE but still did not work.

Comment: I'd suggest abandoning the IDE for now and concentrate on Maven.  Run on the command line.

Comment: I'd also recommend commenting out the plugins that you don't need for now.  Get this working and then add them in.

Comment: the message _`sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target`_ says that there is an issue with your local installed certificates. Look at this [answer to similar problem](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41321038/1988304)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cause: I was behind the company's firewall, which have resulted in not allowing Netbeans downloading the required plugins.

My simple solution was to connect to a different network and run the project and it automatically started downloading the required plugins. I did not have to change any files or configurations at all.

Answer (score 2):

This looks like you may be behind a corporate proxy.

You need to follow the instructions at [Maven - Guide to using proxies](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-proxies.html).

Additionally, I recommend removing the `M2_HOME` and `MAVEN_HOME` environment variables. See [MAVEN_HOME, MVN_HOME or M2_HOME](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26609922/maven-home-mvn-home-or-m2-home/26610326#26610326). Just set the `%PATH%` directly.

Answer (score 0):

The fact is that your maven plugin try to connect to an https remote repository https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 and it failed with invalid security certification. Add following in your pom.xml

```
<pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
      <id>central</id>
      <name>Maven Plugin Repository</name>
      <url>http://repo1.maven.org/maven2</url>
      <layout>default</layout>
      <snapshots>
        <enabled>false</enabled>
      </snapshots>
      <releases>
        <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
      </releases>
    </pluginRepository>
  </pluginRepositories>
```

Comment: No you shouldn't do that. It would be better to fix the problem with the certificate...otherwise you leave the option open for a man in the middle attack...