# Can't download spring-web and spring-webmvc dependencies

Tags: java, spring, maven, netbeans

I have a maven web project in Netbeans.
These are the dependencies in the pom.xml

```
<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
        <version>7.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.5.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.5.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.5.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.5.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.5.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

When i select *Download Declared Dependencies* from *Dependencies* it downloads everything except **spring-web-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar** and **spring-webmvc-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar**. Everytime i do it it stops at 4% and it says it's finished.

Comment: Well i ended up downloading them through mozilla and installing the jars manually. Still i don't get how they didn't got downloaded, i tried restarting netbeans and the internet connection. Weird

Comment: Maven checks if a `jar` have to be downloaded again because maybe a bug has been fixed. Therefore Maven compares the hash of the local and the remote file. If the hash matches he assumes that nothing has been changed. The hash-comparing might take theese 4%.

Comment: Try to delete the directories org/springframework/spring-web and  org/springframework/spring-webmvc from your Maven local repository, and relaunch the maven install on your project.

Answer (score 1):

I have faced the same issue.Just delete .m2 folder created in your home.(c:\Users\user.m2 in windows).and update the project.

IF that is not working then refer this link.
[Problems using Maven and SSL behind proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25911623/problems-using-maven-and-ssl-behind-proxy)

Comment: it happens sometimes, this resolved the same issue some times ago

Comment: Hi Anthony,Now is it working?Are you working beyond proxy?

Comment: Hi, i'm not the OP, i just sayd it happened to me once. And i did exacly what you are saying to resolve my issue. I was saying that your solution was good, and the OP should try that in the first place.