# Spring boot application error : PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException

Tags: spring, maven

I have created spring batch application using Spring Boot. As soon as I open it using Eclipse, I get the below error in pom.xml.

```
Project build error: Non-resolvable parent POM for org.bcbsri.batch:DS-Script:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: Failure to transfer org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:pom:1.5.9.RELEASE from https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer artifact org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:pom:1.5.9.RELEASE from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target and 'parent.relativePath' points at no local POM
```

I downloaded the certificate from https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 and tried to import in newly created jks file. I am not sure how to supply the path of this jks file. I do not have admin rights. Thus I am unable to import this certificate in the Java cacert.

Answer (score 1):

I would say your question is duplicate of [Problems using Maven and SSL behind proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25911623/problems-using-maven-and-ssl-behind-proxy)

You need to import the maven cert to the JDK that you are using. Let's say you download the maven cert as C:\mavenrepocert.cer and using jdk1.8.0_151, you can import the cert as follows from command line:

`keytool -import -file C:\mavenrepocert.cer -keystore "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_151\jre\lib\security\cacerts" -alias mavencert`

Comment: Thanks Umesh..I don't have admin rights. So I can not update the cacert located inside java. Can I have my maven project point to the certificate located at some other place instead of the default java location?

Comment: https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-repository-ssl.html mentions about using MVN_OPTS evn variable. Try setting Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore and Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword to see if you can using another location of the cert file.