# Buidling the maven project is failing

Tags: java, maven, maven-plugin, maven-surefire-plugin

Did mvn clean its failing. Tried to delete the content from m2 folder and try to download still not working any help please appreciated.

[image]

Comment: [Please see why we shouldn't post images of text :)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: Which JDK version are you using?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Maven - unable to find valid certification path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48593183/maven-unable-to-find-valid-certification-path)