# Strange type mismatch error in a legacy LiftWeb application

Tags: scala, lift, scala-2.8

In a legacy application that I'm debugging I have

```scala
import _root_.net.liftweb.mapper._;
import _root_.java.math.MathContext

class User
extends LongKeyedMapper[User]
with IdPK
{
  import User._;

  def getSingleton = User;

  object name       extends MappedString(this, 80);
}

object User
extends User
with LongKeyedMetaMapper[User]
{
  override def fieldOrder = List(id, name);
}
```

which quite literally follows https://exploring.liftweb.net/master/index-8.html.

The code used to compile (using Maven), but now when I'm trying to recompile it years later (and with a newer JDK version) it fails with a strange type error:

```
[ERROR] ...User.scala:21: error: type mismatch;
[INFO]  found   : ....User.id.type (with underlying type object ....User.id)
[INFO]  required: net.liftweb.mapper.MappedField[_ >: String with scala.Long, ....User]{def jdbcFriendly(field: String): java.lang.Comparable[_ >: java.lang.String with java.
lang.Long <: java.io.Serializable] with java.io.Serializable; def dbFieldClass: java.lang.Class[_ >: String with scala.Long] with java.lang.reflect.GenericDeclaration}
[INFO]   override def fieldOrder = List(id, name);
[INFO]                                  ^
```

And a similar error for `name`. To me the types seem to be right, as `Mapped...` classes extend `MappedField` (https://liftweb.net/api/26/api/#net.liftweb.mapper.MappedString).

Versions:

- Lift 2.2 (I tried 2.4 as well).
- Scala 2.8 (I tried 2.8.1. as well).

Any suggestions or ideas what might have gone wrong?

Comment: Did you try to update Maven/Maven Scala plugin as well?

Comment: Also, which newer JDK are you on now? https://github.com/lift/framework/#getting-started states that Lift < 3.0 does not support Java 8. All the more reasons to believe it would not work with JDK newer than 8

Comment: @MateuszKubuszok I'm trying to compile it with Java 8. For a more recent Java version I'd need to update multiple dependencies of the project, which would be quite non-trivial, so I'm trying to avoid this.

Regarding the FAQ , it says

> As of Lift 3.0, you'll need to be running Java 8 to use Lift. For those using Java 6 or Java 7, you'll need to use Lift 2.6 until you can upgrade your Java installation.

Which doesn't imply anything about using Lift 2.6 with Java 8 or newer (that'd be a [converse implication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Converse_(logic))).

Comment: I'm using Apache Maven 3.6.3. I tried to update Scala, but with little results. Either it didn't fix the error, or for newer Scala versions it seemed to be quite a nontrivial upgrade because of Lift dependencies: A newer version of Scala would require to upgrade to Lift 3+.

Comment: Well, it's 13 year old Scala and Lift. About the converse implicitation. You quotes it yourself: _For those using Java 6 or Java 7, you'll need to use Lift 2.6 until you can upgrade your Java installation._. There were some bugs introduced by Java 8: https://github.com/lift/framework/issues?q=is%3Aissue+%22Java+8%22+is%3Aclosed . If the only things that changed was JDK and it made the build break, it's rather good indication that JDK8 cannot be used with this version. At least for compilation, because there is nothing preventing you from trying to compile on JDK7 and run on JDK8.

Comment: Although the only way I can see this project become maintainable would be to pay that technical debt and update dependencies. Perhaps in stages. Bumping by 5 Scala versions might be rough.

Comment: The context detailed is not clear for me. You have a legacy app that haven't run for a while and now when you try to build it and execute it you got that error message? the error was during the upgrade? is it possible that you share the pom.xml? as it was mentioned, the doc says that your version is compatible with jdk 6 and 7, are you using a newer one? in maven, the oldest version I can see for [lift is 2.3](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.liftweb/lift-framework) which is compatible only with scala 2.8.0 and 2.8.1.

Comment: @MateuszKubuszok You're right that JDK8 likely is the cause that broke things. It was the lowest one on which I was able to run my Maven installation. I'll try to get an older Maven version and try with JDK7. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the help of @MateuszKubuszok (comments) I managed to compile the project. Indeed the solution was to use JDK7, with some fiddling:

- An older, pristine Apache Maven installation was needed. I used [3.8.8](https://maven.apache.org/download.cgi#previous-stable-3-8-x-release). The one that came with Debian was version 3.6.3, but packaged on a newer Java version, and so it was failing with:

  > Unsupported major.minor version 52.0

  (See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/11432195/1333025 .)
- JDK7 needed manually adding the public key of https://repo.maven.apache.org/  to `"$JAVA_HOME"/jre/lib/security/cacerts` (https://stackoverflow.com/a/73927521/1333025).