# Can't load snapshot dependency in maven repository

Tags: gradle, build.gradle, gradle-dependencies

Dependency: group: io.github.waterfallmc, name: waterfall-api, version: 1.12-SNAPSHOT

Repository: **https://repo.destroystokyo.com/repository/maven-snapshots/** *(You can check that the dependency is there)*

In *build.gradle*:

Repository:

`maven {
    url "https://repo.destroystokyo.com/repository/maven-snapshots/"
  }`

Dependency:

`compile 'io.github.waterfallmc:waterfall-api:1.12-SNAPSHOT'`

**Output**: [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/95W13zTr)

Comment: Does this help you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25911623/problems-using-maven-and-ssl-behind-proxy your error trace looks likes an SSL issue, check the connection from wherever you are building this by running "echo | openssl s_client -showcerts -servername repo.destroystokyo.com -connect repo.destroystokyo.com:443 2>/dev/null | openssl x509 -inform pem -noout -text" might give some useful information?

Comment: I use Windows, so I can't run this command