# Can't use Maven on Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I installed a new `Eclipse EE 4.9` and downloaded the newest Maven. In `Windwows->Preferences->Maven`:

`->Installations`: I chose the freshly downloaded Maven

`->User Settings`: I chose `[PATH-TO-MAVEN]\conf\settings.xml`

When I try to create a simple Maven project, I get that error:

> Could not calculate build plan: Plugin
>   org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.6 or one of its
>   dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor
>   for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:jar:2.6 Plugin
>   org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.6 or one of its
>   dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor
>   for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:jar:2.6

Also, when I open the `pom.xml` of that project, it says on the line with `<packaging>`:

```
<project [...]>
[...]
  <packaging>war</packaging> // <-- here seems to be an error
</project>
```

that there seems to be an error:

> Multiple annotations found at this line:
>
> - CoreException: Could not calculate build plan: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1 or one of its
>     dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact
>     descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:jar:3.1:
>     ArtifactResolutionException: Failure to transfer
>     org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:pom:3.1 from https://
>     repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository,
>     resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of
>     central has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not 
>     transfer artifact
>     org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:pom:3.1 from/to central
>     (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2):
>     sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building
>     failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException:
>     unable to find valid certification path to requested target
> - Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration: org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:testCompile
>     (execution: default-testCompile, phase: test-compile)

Does anybody have an idea?

Comment: did you actually install maven in eclipse?

Comment: @Sir.Hedgehog: m2e is installed in Eclipse EE per default. I assume, otherwise there wouldn't be the option to create a Maven project.

Comment: nope, same thing happened to me last week. IDE had it installed, but you need to provide the directory that the maven exists. look into it, that might be it.

Comment: Try `Alt` + `F5` to update the project.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there is an issue going over https to the repo.

i.e. sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building

Check the version of Java you are using an ensure that you are not passing an incorrect path to the trust store..

i.e.

-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore

Have a look at https://confluence.atlassian.com/kb/unable-to-connect-to-ssl-services-due-to-pkix-path-building-failed-779355358.html as there are other  resolutions at the bottom of the article..

Just also noted that an issue similar to this has been discussed and anserwed in great detail @ [Problems using Maven and SSL behind proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25911623/problems-using-maven-and-ssl-behind-proxy)..