# Maven stopped downloading dependencies and shows valid certification path to requested target

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

Recently Maven has stopped downloading dependencies. its suggested to use https: . So i changed all http urls to https in the `settings.xml` file. But after that on maven clean and install .It shows the following error

> (https://repo1.maven.org/maven2):
>   sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed:
>   sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to
>   find valid certification path to requested target

Comment: Are you behind a proxy?

Comment: yes i am using a proxy

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Problems using Maven and SSL behind proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25911623/problems-using-maven-and-ssl-behind-proxy)

Comment: I think that should help.I will check this. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If you are behind any proxy, Please configure proxy in `settings.xml`

```
  <proxies>
    <proxy>
      <id>proxy</id>
      <active>true</active>
      <protocol>your_protocol</protocol>
      <host>your_host</host>
      <port>your_port</port>
    </proxy>

  </proxies>
```