# Java SSL - Certificates added to CACERTS do not work after restart

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, ssl-certificate, keytool

I am setting up a new machine with eclipse Oxygen 4.7. I spent some time getting certificates added to CACERTS so that I could access an external maven repository and access the eclipse marketplace. On Friday afternoon I had everything working. I could reach the eclipse marketplace and maven was able to download my dependencies.  Over the weekend I rebooted my machine and my certificates no longer work.  I am getting...

> Caused by:
> sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to
> find valid certification path to requested target.

Am I missing a step or doing something wrong when adding my certs?  These are my steps...

1. Download the cert for the maven repo from the website. I can navigate to the site fine in my browser.  I use the certificate export tool. I export the cert as base 64.
   [image]
2. I add the cert to CACERTS using keytool.

[image]

3. If I restart eclipse the cert will now get picked up and on the first try I am able to connect to the maven repo.  This is true for the marketplace certificate as well.  If I restart my machine after this (might also be triggered by just restarting eclipse again, I will test this) the certs no longer works.

I only have one version of java installed, jdk1.8.0_202.

[image]

I tried explicitly setting the path to CACERTS in the eclipse.ini file but that did not make a difference.  I do have the settings.xml set up for maven.  As I have issues connecting to both my maven repo and the eclipse market place I do not think settings.xml is the culprit. Any ideas would be most appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: This a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25911623/problems-using-maven-and-ssl-behind-proxy?

Comment: My question includes many of the answers in the other post. I would say my question is more specific on how to properly install certs.

Comment: @Kachopsticks did you manage to fix this issue?

Comment: @sub not a great solution or explanation, but I think it helps to start with adding certs higher up in the chain. I would maybe try avoiding adding the bottom level cert and see if that works.