# Maven Errror Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-source-plugin:pom:3.0.1 from/to central

Tags: java, maven, azure-devops, azure-pipelines-yaml, azure-devops-self-hosted-agent

I am trying to compile my code using maven, getting below error,

## Environment

i am using azure devops server and using build pipeline
Maven Errror Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-source-plugin:pom:3.0.1 from/to central

`2021-02-26T11:43:14.4764714Z [ERROR] Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-source-plugin:3.0.1 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-source-plugin:jar:3.0.1: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-source-plugin:pom:3.0.1 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Transfer failed for https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-source-plugin/3.0.1/maven-source-plugin-3.0.1.pom ProxyInfo{host='12.3.4.59', userName='null', port=80, type='http', nonProxyHosts='null'}: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target -> [Help 1]`

`Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target`

[image]

[image]

Comment: It looks like your proxy `ProxyInfo{host='10.218.129.49', userName='null' ... PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderExcepti` is using the wrong certificate or you are using a JDK7 and less... you should upgrade to JDK8+

Comment: i have higher version of java installed , i have attached image for reference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the error message:

```
Transfer failed for https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2...unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

It shows the Maven is trying to download an indirect dependency from Maven Central Repository located at `https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven`2, which is a **secured HTTP server (HTTPS)**. So the issue may comes from your certificate itself or your network.

For the certificate, try to `https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2` and downloaded the certificate, then added it to the cacerts, with the command:

```
keytool -import -alias example -keystore  .\cacerts -file example.cer
```

Please try to check more info from this thread ["PKIX path building failed" and "unable to find valid certification path to requested target"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21076179/pkix-path-building-failed-and-unable-to-find-valid-certification-path-to-requ)

For the network, please try to access that very URL on you browser and check if it's operational. If you really can't access the Maven Central Repo with HTTPS from your browser, maybe it's becouse you are behind some proxy rule that is keeping you from download the server certificate.

You could set the **settings.xml** file is like below:

```
 <proxies>
     <proxy>
         <active>true</active>
         <protocol>https</protocol>
         <host>MY_COMPANY_HOST</host>
         <port>8080</port>
         <username>MY_USERNAME</username>
         <password>MY_PASSWORD</password>
         <nonProxyHosts>localhost</nonProxyHosts>
     </proxy>
     <proxy>
         <active>true</active>
         <protocol>http</protocol>
         <host>MY_COMPANY_HOST</host>
         <port>8080</port>
         <username>MY_USERNAME</username>
         <password>MY_PASSWORD</password>
         <nonProxyHosts>localhost</nonProxyHosts>
     </proxy>
 </proxies>
```

And check the thread [Problems using Maven and SSL behind proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25911623/problems-using-maven-and-ssl-behind-proxy) for some more details.

Comment: yes i am able to access the URL from the host browser

Comment: @SatyamPandey, Have you check your certificate?

Comment: not sure how to check the same , however the depdedencies which my self hosted agent is not able to download i am to access the same on web broswer of azure devops server, i update the details

Comment: Hello Issue reappeared, again mvn is not able to download dependencies from central