# Maven - "Failed to read artifact descriptor" for a dependency that is not specified in pom.xml

Tags: java, maven

I have a project **std-web** with repository and dependency as below:

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>MDM</id>
        <url>My devnexus URL</url>
        <name>My Repo</name>
    </repository>
</repositories>
    
<dependencies>
...
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.melissadata</groupId>
    <artifactId>mdPhone</artifactId>
    <version>2.0</version>
</dependency>
...
<dependencies>
```

This std-web also has a dependency of another project:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.proj.std</groupId>
    <artifactId>std-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.0</version>
</dependency>
```

When I *clean install* the **std-api** project, it is successful. And when I *clean install* the **std-web** project, I get this error:

> Failed to execute goal on project std-web: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.proj.std:std-web:war:2.0: Failed to collect dependencies at com.proj.std:std-api:jar:2.0 -> com.melissadata:mdPhone:jar:3.0: Failed to read artifact descriptor for com.melissadata:mdPhone:jar:3.0: Could not transfer artifact com.melissadata:mdPhone:pom:3.0 from/to MDM (): PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target -> [Help 1]

I have verified pretty enough to confirm that the specific dependency *com.melissadata:mdPhone:jar:3.0* has not been specified anywhere in both the **std-api** and **std-web** pom files. Both the **std-api** and **std-web** projects is pointing to the same jdk, which means, it has the same *cacerts*. No issues in devnexus certificate since **std-api** had a successful build as well.

Please help throwing some light on how to fix this.

Comment: Did you have a look at `mvn dependency:tree`?

Comment: @JFabianMeier that won't work as dependency tree can't be created until dependencies are resolved.

Comment: Your maven is configured to fetch artifacts from repository that has invalid SSL certificate (according to JVM keystore). See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25911623/problems-using-maven-and-ssl-behind-proxy)

Comment: The problem is `PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target` . Question: Which Java version? Which Maven version?