# not able to build maven project due to "unable to find valid certification path to requested target"

Tags: maven, jasper-reports

I am not able to build my project code on y machine. the code is working fine in my teammates' machines. The log I am getting in the problems tab of the spring tool suite is given below

```
Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
Failed to read artifact descriptor for com.lowagie:itext:jar:2.1.7.js8

org.eclipse.aether.resolution.ArtifactDescriptorException: Failed to read artifact descriptor for com.lowagie:itext:jar:2.1.7.js8
    at org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.loadPom(DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.java:255)
    at org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.readArtifactDescriptor(DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.java:171)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.collect.DefaultDependencyCollector.resolveCachedArtifactDescriptor(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:538)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.collect.DefaultDependencyCollector.getArtifactDescriptorResult(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:523)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.collect.DefaultDependencyCollector.processDependency(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:410)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.collect.DefaultDependencyCollector.processDependency(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:362)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.collect.DefaultDependencyCollector.process(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:349)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.collect.DefaultDependencyCollector.doRecurse(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:506)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.collect.DefaultDependencyCollector.processDependency(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:458)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.collect.DefaultDependencyCollector.processDependency(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:362)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.collect.DefaultDependencyCollector.process(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:349)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.collect.DefaultDependencyCollector.collectDependencies(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:254)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultRepositorySystem.collectDependencies(DefaultRepositorySystem.java:284)
    at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectDependenciesResolver.resolve(DefaultProjectDependenciesResolver.java:169)
    at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectBuilder.resolveDependencies(DefaultProjectBuilder.java:227)
    at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectBuilder.build(DefaultProjectBuilder.java:200)
    at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectBuilder.build(DefaultProjectBuilder.java:124)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenImpl.readMavenProject(MavenImpl.java:630)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.registry.DefaultMavenDependencyResolver.resolveProjectDependencies(DefaultMavenDependencyResolver.java:65)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.registry.ProjectRegistryManager.refreshPhase2(ProjectRegistryManager.java:550)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.registry.ProjectRegistryManager.lambda$3(ProjectRegistryManager.java:514)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.executeBare(MavenExecutionContext.java:179)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.execute(MavenExecutionContext.java:153)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.registry.ProjectRegistryManager.refresh(ProjectRegistryManager.java:512)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.registry.ProjectRegistryManager.refresh(ProjectRegistryManager.java:364)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.registry.ProjectRegistryManager.refresh(ProjectRegistryManager.java:315)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.ProjectConfigurationManager.updateProjectConfiguration0(ProjectConfigurationManager.java:409)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.ProjectConfigurationManager.lambda$1(ProjectConfigurationManager.java:358)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.executeBare(MavenExecutionContext.java:179)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.execute(MavenExecutionContext.java:153)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.execute(MavenExecutionContext.java:101)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenImpl.execute(MavenImpl.java:1370)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.ProjectConfigurationManager.updateProjectConfiguration(ProjectConfigurationManager.java:357)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.ui.internal.UpdateMavenProjectJob.runInWorkspace(UpdateMavenProjectJob.java:80)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.InternalWorkspaceJob.run(InternalWorkspaceJob.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:63)
Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.resolution.ArtifactResolutionException: Could not transfer artifact com.lowagie:itext:pom:2.1.7.js8 from/to jaspersoft-third-party (http://jaspersoft.jfrog.io/jaspersoft/third-party-ce-artifacts/): PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:424)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifacts(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:229)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifact(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:207)
    at org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.loadPom(DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.java:240)
    ... 35 more
Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.transfer.ArtifactTransferException: Could not transfer artifact com.lowagie:itext:pom:2.1.7.js8 from/to jaspersoft-third-party (http://jaspersoft.jfrog.io/jaspersoft/third-party-ce-artifacts/):  : sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at io.takari.aether.connector.AetherRepositoryConnector$2.wrap(AetherRepositoryConnector.java:889)
    at io.takari.aether.connector.AetherRepositoryConnector$2.wrap(AetherRepositoryConnector.java:1)
    at io.takari.aether.connector.AetherRepositoryConnector$GetTask.flush(AetherRepositoryConnector.java:659)
    at io.takari.aether.connector.AetherRepositoryConnector.get(AetherRepositoryConnector.java:337)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.performDownloads(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:513)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:401)
    ... 38 more
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:131)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:369)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:312)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:307)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T12CertificateConsumer.checkServerCerts(CertificateMessage.java:654)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T12CertificateConsumer.onCertificate(CertificateMessage.java:473)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T12CertificateConsumer.consume(CertificateMessage.java:369)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLHandshake.consume(SSLHandshake.java:396)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.dispatch(HandshakeContext.java:480)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.dispatch(HandshakeContext.java:458)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.dispatch(TransportContext.java:199)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLTransport.decode(SSLTransport.java:172)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.decode(SSLSocketImpl.java:1506)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readHandshakeRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1416)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:451)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:422)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connectTls(RealConnection.java:336)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.establishProtocol(RealConnection.java:300)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connect(RealConnection.java:185)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.ExchangeFinder.findConnection(ExchangeFinder.java:224)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.ExchangeFinder.findHealthyConnection(ExchangeFinder.java:107)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.ExchangeFinder.find(ExchangeFinder.java:87)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.Transmitter.newExchange(Transmitter.java:169)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.ConnectInterceptor.intercept(ConnectInterceptor.java:41)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:142)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:117)
    at okhttp3.internal.cache.CacheInterceptor.intercept(CacheInterceptor.java:94)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:142)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:117)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.BridgeInterceptor.intercept(BridgeInterceptor.java:93)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:142)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.intercept(RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.java:88)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:142)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:117)
    at okhttp3.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(RealCall.java:221)
    at okhttp3.RealCall.execute(RealCall.java:81)
    at io.takari.aether.okhttp.OkHttpAetherClient.execute(OkHttpAetherClient.java:215)
    at io.takari.aether.okhttp.OkHttpAetherClient.get(OkHttpAetherClient.java:161)
    at io.takari.aether.connector.AetherRepositoryConnector$GetTask.getResponse(AetherRepositoryConnector.java:655)
    at io.takari.aether.connector.AetherRepositoryConnector$GetTask.resumableGet(AetherRepositoryConnector.java:600)
    at io.takari.aether.connector.AetherRepositoryConnector$GetTask.run(AetherRepositoryConnector.java:481)
    at io.takari.aether.connector.AetherRepositoryConnector$DirectExecutor.execute(AetherRepositoryConnector.java:915)
    at io.takari.aether.connector.AetherRepositoryConnector.get(AetherRepositoryConnector.java:331)
    ... 40 more
Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at java.base/sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:439)
    at java.base/sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(PKIXValidator.java:306)
    at java.base/sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Validator.java:264)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:231)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:132)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T12CertificateConsumer.checkServerCerts(CertificateMessage.java:638)
    ... 78 more
Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at java.base/sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.build(SunCertPathBuilder.java:141)
    at java.base/sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(SunCertPathBuilder.java:126)
    at java.base/java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(CertPathBuilder.java:297)
    at java.base/sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:434)
    ... 83 more
    pom.xml /project    line 1  Maven Dependency Problem
```

I tried adding the certificate to cacerts file for both the below URLs,

1. http://jaspersoft.jfrog.io/jaspersoft/third-party-ce-artifacts
2. https://jaspersoft.jfrog.io/jaspersoft/third-party-ce-artifacts

But no luck. I am using jdk-11.0.12 and apache-maven-3.8.2 and the only jasper dependency in the pom is,

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
    <artifactId>jasperreports</artifactId>
    <version>6.16.0</version>
</dependency>
```

I tried maven update multiple times.

Can anyone help me?

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25911623/problems-using-maven-and-ssl-behind-proxy) question does not solve my issue..

**ANSWER:**
maven was blocking the dependency download from HTTP (not secured) channels. i added a mirror in maven settings.xml to fix this issue.

```
    <mirror>
      <id>insecure-repo</id>
      <mirrorOf>external:http:*</mirrorOf>
      <url>http://jaspersoft.jfrog.io/jaspersoft/third-party-ce-artifacts/</url>
      <blocked>false</blocked>
    </mirror>
```

Comment: How did you add the repository?

Comment: using the default repository. C:\Users\sanal\.m2\repository

Comment: You did not add the repository with JasperReports 3rd party libraries? `<repository>
 <id>jaspersoft-third-party</id>
 <url>http://jaspersoft.jfrog.io/jaspersoft/third-party-ce-artifacts/</url>
</repository>`

Comment: where should i add this? and if it is a mandatory thing how come my teammates are able to build the project ?

Comment: https://github.com/TIBCOSoftware/jasperreports/issues/148

Comment: I added it like this,
<repositories>
  <!-- jhipster-needle-maven-repository -->
 <repository>
  <id>jaspersoft-third-party</id>
  <url>http://jaspersoft.jfrog.io/jaspersoft/third-party-ce-artifacts/</url>
 </repository>
 </repositories>

Comment: But i am not able to download the dependency..
9/15/21, 5:39:19 PM IST: [INFO] Downloaded http://jaspersoft.jfrog.io/jaspersoft/third-party-ce-artifacts/org/springframework/cloud/spring-cloud-starter-sleuth/2.2.2.RELEASE/spring-cloud-starter-sleuth-2.2.2.RELEASE-javadoc.jar
9/15/21, 5:39:19 PM IST: [ERROR] Could not download javadoc for org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-sleuth:2.2.2.RELEASE

Similar errors are displayed in maven console.