# Cannot create project when using cloud dataflow plugin for Eclipse

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

I want to try setup the development environment on Windows with Eclipse. But failed at the final step after successfully setting project id and gs bucket. The errors seems related to network (**I have set proxy in Eclipse**), I guess Maven need to set proxy, but how? Can someone confirm it? Thanks.

"Error encountered when trying to create project"

```
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext.run(ModalContext.java:423)
at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.run(WizardDialog.java:1059)
at com.google.cloud.dataflow.eclipse.ui.wizard.NewDataflowProjectWizard.performFinish(NewDataflowProjectWizard.java:50)
at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.finishPressed(WizardDialog.java:853)
at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.buttonPressed(WizardDialog.java:438)
at org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.Dialog$2.widgetSelected(Dialog.java:619)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(TypedListener.java:248)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4353)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1061)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4172)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3761)
at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.runEventLoop(Window.java:832)
at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.open(Window.java:808)
at org.eclipse.ui.actions.NewProjectAction.run(NewProjectAction.java:117)
at org.eclipse.jface.action.Action.runWithEvent(Action.java:519)
at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.handleWidgetSelection(ActionContributionItem.java:595)
at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.access$2(ActionContributionItem.java:511)
at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem$5.handleEvent(ActionContributionItem.java:420)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4353)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1061)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4172)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3761)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$9.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1151)
at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1032)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:148)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:636)
at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:579)
at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:150)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:135)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:380)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:235)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:648)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:603)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1465)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: org.eclipse.core.runtime.CoreException: Could not resolve artifact com.google.cloud.dataflow:google-cloud-dataflow-java-archetypes-examples:pom:LATEST
at com.google.cloud.dataflow.eclipse.core.project.DataflowProjectCreator.run(DataflowProjectCreator.java:207)
at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext$ModalContextThread.run(ModalContext.java:122)
Caused by: org.eclipse.core.runtime.CoreException: Could not resolve artifact com.google.cloud.dataflow:google-cloud-dataflow-java-archetypes-examples:pom:LATEST
at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenImpl$5.call(MavenImpl.java:776)
at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenImpl$5.call(MavenImpl.java:1)
at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.executeBare(MavenExecutionContext.java:176)
at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.execute(MavenExecutionContext.java:151)
at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.execute(MavenExecutionContext.java:99)
at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenImpl.resolve(MavenImpl.java:743)
at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenImpl.resolve(MavenImpl.java:720)
at com.google.cloud.dataflow.eclipse.core.project.DataflowArtifactRetriever.archetypePom(DataflowArtifactRetriever.java:54)
at com.google.cloud.dataflow.eclipse.core.project.DataflowProjectCreator.defaultArchetypeVersions(DataflowProjectCreator.java:250)
at com.google.cloud.dataflow.eclipse.core.project.DataflowProjectCreator.run(DataflowProjectCreator.java:204)
... 1 more
```

"Couldn't get archetype versions to use as default"

```
org.eclipse.core.runtime.CoreException: Could not resolve artifact com.google.cloud.dataflow:google-cloud-dataflow-java-archetypes-examples:pom:LATEST
at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenImpl$5.call(MavenImpl.java:776)
at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenImpl$5.call(MavenImpl.java:1)
at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.executeBare(MavenExecutionContext.java:176)
at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.execute(MavenExecutionContext.java:151)
at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.execute(MavenExecutionContext.java:99)
at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenImpl.resolve(MavenImpl.java:743)
at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenImpl.resolve(MavenImpl.java:720)
at com.google.cloud.dataflow.eclipse.core.project.DataflowArtifactRetriever.archetypePom(DataflowArtifactRetriever.java:54)
at com.google.cloud.dataflow.eclipse.core.project.DataflowProjectCreator.defaultArchetypeVersions(DataflowProjectCreator.java:250)
at com.google.cloud.dataflow.eclipse.core.project.DataflowProjectCreator.run(DataflowProjectCreator.java:204)
at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext$ModalContextThread.run(ModalContext.java:122)
Contains: Failed to resolve version for com.google.cloud.dataflow:google-cloud-dataflow-java-archetypes-examples:pom:LATEST: Could not find metadata com.google.cloud.dataflow:google-cloud-dataflow-java-archetypes-examples/maven-metadata.xml in local (C:\Users\ztang16\.m2\repository)
org.eclipse.aether.resolution.VersionResolutionException: Failed to resolve version for com.google.cloud.dataflow:google-cloud-dataflow-java-archetypes-examples:pom:LATEST: Could not find metadata com.google.cloud.dataflow:google-cloud-dataflow-java-archetypes-examples/maven-metadata.xml in local (C:\Users\ztang16\.m2\repository)
at        org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultVersionResolver.resolveVersion(DefaultVersionResolver.java:313)
at  org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:302)
at  org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifacts(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:246)
at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifact(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:223)
at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultRepositorySystem.resolveArtifact(DefaultRepositorySystem.java:294)
at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenImpl$5.call(MavenImpl.java:753)
at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenImpl$5.call(MavenImpl.java:1)
at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.executeBare(MavenExecutionContext.java:176)
at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.execute(MavenExecutionContext.java:151)
at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.execute(MavenExecutionContext.java:99)
at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenImpl.resolve(MavenImpl.java:743)
at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenImpl.resolve(MavenImpl.java:720)
at com.google.cloud.dataflow.eclipse.core.project.DataflowArtifactRetriever.archetypePom(DataflowArtifactRetriever.java:54)
at com.google.cloud.dataflow.eclipse.core.project.DataflowProjectCreator.defaultArchetypeVersions(DataflowProjectCreator.java:250)
at com.google.cloud.dataflow.eclipse.core.project.DataflowProjectCreator.run(DataflowProjectCreator.java:204)
at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext$ModalContextThread.run(ModalContext.java:122)
Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.transfer.MetadataNotFoundException: Could not find metadata com.google.cloud.dataflow:google-cloud-dataflow-java-archetypes-examples/maven-metadata.xml in local (C:\Users\ztang16\.m2\repository)
at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultMetadataResolver.resolve(DefaultMetadataResolver.java:247)
at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultMetadataResolver.resolveMetadata(DefaultMetadataResolver.java:205)
at org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultVersionResolver.resolveVersion(DefaultVersionResolver.java:250)
... 15 more
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be hitting an issue when resolving the latest version of our Maven archetype for the `examples` project. The most inner exception seems to be:

```
org.eclipse.aether.transfer.MetadataNotFoundException:
Could not find metadata com.google.cloud.dataflow:google-cloud-dataflow-java-archetypes-examples/maven-metadata.xml
in local (C:\Users\YOUR-USERNAME\.m2\repository)
```

This indicates a problem in your local repository.

We have not seen this specific error before, but tangentially related problems have been resolved by manually deleting the following directory on your local machine and retrying.

```
C:\Users\YOUR-USERNAME\.m2\repository\com\google\cloud\dataflow\dataflow:google-cloud-dataflow-java-archetypes-examples
```

This would force Maven to reinitialize that part of the local repository, and perhaps recreate the missing metadata file.

---

That said, we have slightly changed how our Eclipse plugin interacts with the `m2e` plugin. The new code doesn't take this path through `m2e` at all. It is quite likely that this would be a non-issue with an updated code. We tentatively plan to release a new version next week, which would contain this change.

---

Now, there also could be an issue with a HTTP proxy configuration in your environment. I found [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7737710/maven-plugin-not-using-eclipses-proxy-settings), which explains how to configure advanced options of the M2Eclipse plugin, including the proxy settings. Dataflow Eclipse plugin is built on top of M2Eclipse and I would expect those setting to apply automatically.

Comment: I deleted the files and try again. But still same error.
One of my question is that is proxy set for Eclipse enough? or maven need proxy also?

Comment: Added clarification about the proxy settings. Please let us know if the problem persists.

Comment: It can set up the project when I set the proxy for Maven. But still some error:
`CoreException while adding Dataflow Nature to created project zk_hello_gdf`

Comment: and `Nature com.google.cloud.dataflow.DataflowJavaProjectNature is missing prerequisite nature: org.eclipse.jdt.core.javanature.`

Comment: `Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration: org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (execution: default-resources, phase: process-resources)`

Comment: additonally, when I tried to config the run configurations:
`java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Path for project must have only one segment.`. Is it saying that I cannot use this project name ("zk_hello_gdf")?

Comment: There may be additional environmental issues going on. We'd need to see the full exception text of new exceptions to provide additional insight. Can you reach to us over email at dataflow-feedback@google.com with more information? Alternatively, you can split off this question into separate StackOverflow questions with more information and we can try to answer those.