# Maven Setup on Eclipse / IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, intellij-idea, maven-2

Getting error when setting up Eclipse and IntelliJ with maven:

1) Eclipse ------->

a) Error 1:

```
Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.transfer.ArtifactTransferException: Could not tran
sfer artifact org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:pom:2.7 from/to ce
ntral (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): repo.maven.apache.org
```

b) Error 2:

```
CoreException: Could not calculate build plan: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1 or one of its dependencies could not be 
     resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:jar:3.1: ArtifactResolutionException: Failure to transfer 
     org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:pom:3.1 from http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be 
     reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-
     compiler-plugin:pom:3.1 from/to central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): repo.maven.apache.org
    - CoreException: Could not calculate build plan: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1 or one of its dependencies could not be 
     resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:jar:3.1: ArtifactResolutionException: Could not transfer artifact 
     org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:pom:3.1 from/to central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): repo.maven.apache.org
    - Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration: org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:testCompile (execution: default-
     testCompile, phase: test-compile)
    - Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration: org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (execution: default-compile, 
     phase: compile)
```

2) IntelliJ Error ------->

```
Failed to read Artifact descriptor
```

... I have set up Maven on Windows and tried to compile from Commandline too but getting error:

3) MVN Command-Line Error ------->

a)

```
Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.transfer.ArtifactTransferException: Could not tran
    sfer artifact org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:pom:2.7 from/to ce
    ntral (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): repo.maven.apache.org
```

b) `Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: repo.maven.apache.org`

Comment: Are you trying this from behind a firewall?  Check that nothing is blocking your traffic to repo.maven.apache.org

Comment: Yes I am behind a firewall and have added PROXY in IntelliJ IDEA which when tested thru the <Test Connection>, shows its successful.
I get this error for each Dependency in MAVEN POM.xml file:

FAILED TO READ ARTIFACT DESCRIPTOR

Comment: Do you have your proxy setup for http AND https? How are you testing the connection?

Comment: In INTELLIJ IDEA --> Settings --> HTTP PROXY, I have selected 
- Manual Proxy Configuration
- HTTP (NOT SOCKS)

Comment: Take a step back and try `ping repo.maven.apache.org` and see if you get a response. If not, setup proxy settings in your machine. If your workplace gives an autoproxy use that.

Comment: For Eclipse and the MVN command line see https://stackoverflow.com/q/7737710

Comment: IntelliJ is fixed... I created <settings.xml> and added Proxy information to it. Thats all, the dependencies kept flowing in. @howlger, will check the post you mentioned. Thanks all.